# Returning the "next" time in a list of times

Tags: android, list, datetime, time

I'm looking for a reference example of how to read times in a list, and return the one that occurs "next."

I'm working on a schedule app, but currently I'm doing a very nested bunch of `if` statements that look something like this:

```
if (Time.compare(bus1.getTime(), currentTime) > 0) {
                setTimeLabelLOY(bus1);
            } else {
                if (Time.compare(bus2.getTime(), currentTime) > 0) {
                    setTimeLabelLOY(bus2);
                } else {
                    if (Time.compare(bus3.getTime(), currentTime) > 0) {
                        setTimeLabelLOY(bus3);
                    } else {
                        if (Time.compare(bus4.getTime(), currentTime) > 0) {
                            setTimeLabelLOY(bus4);
                        } else {
                            if (Time.compare(bus5.getTime(), currentTime) > 0) {
                                setTimeLabelLOY(bus5);
                            } else {
                                if (Time.compare(bus6.getTime(), currentTime) > 0) {
                                    setTimeLabelLOY(bus6);
```

Obviously my `Bus` class contains `Time` elements that I have hardcoded. I would prefer to simply read a list of times and output whichever one is next. Or maybe make an array of times and have them sorted based on the current time?

Any advice or examples on how to do this better would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you store all of your buses in a List you could use:

```
List<Bus> buses = new ArrayList<Bus>();
buses.add(bus1);
// etc

for(Bus bus : buses) {
    if(Time.compare(bus.getTime(), currentTime) > 0) {
        setTimeLabelLOY(bus);
        break;
    }
}
```

You could also store all of the bus data in a SQLite database and then use a simple query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Buses WHERE time > currentTime LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: *Smacks head* OF course I should have just looped it! Thank you!

I'm actually really interested in your SQLite response. I would love to store my Bus times on a server (that I can update) and have the app query it. Do you know where I could learn more about this type of relationship with my Android app? I'm totally new to SQLite.

Comment: Learning SQLite will take a little time, since SQL is a language in itself. But should be able to find some basic information in books that [teach Android](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/android/info) or you get a [SQLite specific book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite#References). I haven't read any of those myself so I cannot suggest one in particular.